# Google App Engine / Java - inconsistent ORDER BY

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, bigtable

I am using JPA on top of App Engine (I am quite new to both) and I am currently facing a behaviour I do not understand.

Each time I refresh the page, the order of the fetched items changes.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Set<Cast> results = new HashSet<Cast>();
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(FIND_ALL_SORTED_BY_DESCENDING_BROADCAST_DATE);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Cast> casts = query.getResultList();
for (Cast cast : casts) {
    if (verifySecondaryFields(cast)) {
        results.add(synchronizeTechnicalFields(cast));
    }
}
entityManager.close();
return Collections.unmodifiableSet(results);
```

where `FIND_ALL_SORTED_BY_DESCENDING_BROADCAST_DATE` actually is `SELECT cast FROM Cast cast ORDER BY cast.broadcastDate DESC`.

`entityManagerFactory` is an autowired member of my repository class.

The thing is the `ORDER BY` clause seems to be ignored and the results show up randomly. Can you spot what is wrong?

Comment: In the mean time, I guess reading http://labs.google.com/papers/bigtable.html won't harm :P

Comment: and the javadoc for HashSet ...

Comment: and the worse is that I already knew it ;(
Shame on me again.

Comment: `FIND_ALL_SORTED_BY_DESCENDING_BROADCAST_DATE` seems like a particularly verbose way to make your code less readable. Why not just include the actual query string there, instead?

Comment: this way, I gather all my queries in 1 place (that is, before the method declarations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets don't preserve order. Lists do. Try `List<Cast> = new ArrayList<Cast>();` and carry on from there.

Comment: oooooh, shame on me :)
I feel so stupid, but thanks for your answer :)